# Elementary algebra problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Consider the following problem (drawn from Stanford Math Competition 2014): "Find the minimum value of $\frac{1}{x-y}+\frac{1}{y-z}+ \frac{1}{x-z}$ for for reals $x > y > z$ given $(x − y)(y − z)(x − z) = 17.$"

Method 1 (official solution): Combining the first two terms, we have
$\frac{x−z}{(x-y)(y-z)} + \frac{1}{x-z}= \frac{(x-z)^2}{17}+ \frac{1}{x-z}.$

What remains is to find the minimum value of $f(a) = \frac{a^2}{17} + \frac{1}{a} = \frac{a^2}{17} + \frac{1}{2a}+ \frac{1}{2a}$ for positive values of $a.$ Using AM-GM, we get $f(a) \geq \frac{3}{68^{1/3}}$.

Method 2: Let $x-y:=a, \; y-z:=b, \; x-z:=c.$  Then $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}= \frac{ab+bc+ac}{17}= \frac{3}{17}\frac{ab+bc+ac}{3} \geq \frac{3}{17} (a^2b^2c^2)^{1/3} =\frac{3}{17^{1/3}}.$

So Method 2 seems to give a sharper bound than the official solution.  Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official solution is wrong. The equality happens when $$\frac{a^2}{17}=\frac1{2a}$$ or $a^3=\frac{17}2<a^3$. Note that in your solution, the equality does not happen either.

**Edit**: I would solve the problem as follows.

Let $a=x-y,b=y-z$ then $ab(a+b)=17$ and we need to minimize
$$\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1{a+b}=\frac{(a+b)^2+ab}{ab(a+b)}=\frac{(a+b)^2+ab}{17}.$$
We then need to minimize $$f(t) = (a+b)^2+ab=t^2+\frac{17}{t},$$ where $a+b=t$ satisfying $$t^2\ge 4ab=\frac{68}{t},\text{ or } t\ge \sqrt[3]{68}.$$
It's easy to see that
$$f'(t)=2t-\frac{17}{t^2}=\frac{2t^3-17}{t^2}>0.$$
So $f(t)$ attains its minimum at $t=\sqrt[3]{68}$. That is $x-z=\sqrt[3]{68}$ and $x-y=y-z=\frac{\sqrt[3]{68}}{2}$ and we see that the minimum is $\displaystyle\color{red}{\frac{5}{\sqrt[3]{68}}}$.

Comment: You minimize the function f(t), by setting its derivative equal to zero and testing the second derivative to be positive for it to be minimum.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You are using AM_GM  when you say $t^2\geq 4ab$, which is very selective of using two terms a and b when you should include all three terms.

Comment: @satishramanathan: First, $f'(t)$ is positive, so $f(t)$ attains minimum when $t$ is minimum. Second, why do I need to include three terms?

Comment: the ranges x>y>z along with the condition that ab(a+b) = 17 will force you to use AM-GM on a and b alone, only on that values of a+b will $(a-b)^2 = 0$ and will turn negative if I used AM GM on all three terms, it will minimize the value of f(t) but will not meet the criteria of the product being equal to 17. Hence you are absolutely right on your answer and my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

In the second solution, when $=$ in $\ge$ is satisfied, $a=b=c$. But then, $abc=17$ and $a+b=c$ makes the contradiction.

Comment: How did you get to that $f(a)$?
I got to the same one as the OP.

Comment: @DarthGeek I think OP wanted to define $f(a)$ as $\frac{1}{x-y}+\frac{1}{y-z}+ \frac{1}{x-z}$, where $a=x-z$. What OP missed was the last term, $\frac{1}{x-z}$.

Comment: The definition of f(a) is correct, but I don't believe that I missed the last term...

Comment: No he didn't:

$$\frac{1}{x-y}+\frac{1}{y-z}+ \frac{1}{x-z} = \frac{(y-z)+(x-y)}{(x-y)(y-z)} + \frac{1}{x-z} =\\ = \frac{x-z}{x-z}·\frac{x-z}{(x-y)(y-z)}+ \frac{1}{x-z} = \frac{(x-z)^2}{17} + \frac{1}{x-z}$$

Comment: Oh... that was my mistake. I edited my answer.